# How to download a file when a custom header is needed?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to download from a private repository in GitHub, so I need to pass the headers `Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}` and `Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw`.

For example, with curl: `curl -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -o file.yaml -L https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/file.yaml`

Looking for information about how to download a file in Kotlin, I found a few examples, and I'm using the following:

```
fun downloadFile(url: URL, fileName: String) {
    url.openStream().use { Files.copy(it, Paths.get(fileName)) }
}
```

How can I pass those two headers?

Comment: I would advise to use an HTTP client instead of reading from the URL directly. If you're on JRE 11+, you can use the built-in [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) for instance. There are also plenty of libraries for this: Ktor, OkHttp, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a [link](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-do-you-need-another-http-client-2eda5f5efc7a) that helped me with this:

```
fun downloadFile(url: URL, fileName: String, githubToken: String) {
    url.openConnection().apply {
        setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.raw")
        setRequestProperty("Authorization", "token "+ githubToken)
    }.getInputStream().use { Files.copy(it, Paths.get(fileName)) }
}
```